# Google Places Service not displaying exact results

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I Have 3 Issues,
first one : If i select banks for one km and two km and so on in right bottom listings by indiacom yellow pages keeps on coming. 
second one : If i select bank for one km and then i select bank for two km the first set of banks for 1 km disappers and bank from 1 km to 2 km only appears
third one : if i select bank within 1 km the banks appears outside the circle diameter of 1000meters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body, #map-canvas {
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px
  }
</style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">    
  </script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&libraries=places">    </script>
<script>
 var cityCircle;
var marker;
var clickmarker;
var latilong;
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var myCenter;
var markers = [];
var circles = [];
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

function initialize() 
{
        var styles = [
            {
    "stylers": [
  { "visibility": "on" },
  { "saturation": -40 },
  { "hue": "#F0FAFF" },
  { "weight": 1.7 }
                ]
            }
                    ]

myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(13.0839, 80.2700);
var options = {
mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: ['Styled']
},
center:myCenter,
zoom: 14,

mapTypeId: 'Styled'
};
var div = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
map = new google.maps.Map(div, options);
var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });
map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);


}



function setPlaces()
{

    var placeType = document.getElementById('cmbMoreFunction').options[document.getElementById('cmbMoreFunction').selectedIndex].value;
    var kiloDistance=document.getElementById('kilometers').options[document.getElementById('kilometers').selectedIndex].value ;

    var request = {
    location:myCenter,
    radius: parseInt(kiloDistance),
    types: [placeType]
};
 function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   markers[i].setMap(null);

}
for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
  circles[i].setMap(null);

}

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  createMarker(results[i] , placeType);

}
 }
}
function createMarker(place , placeType)
{

var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: place.geometry.location
});
  marker.setIcon({
    url: placeType + '.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(70, 71),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 14),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    });

marker.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});

markers.push(marker);
circles.push(cityCircle);
}



  var circleOptions = {

    map: map,
    center: myCenter,
    radius: parseInt(kiloDistance),
    };
if (kiloDistance != -1) {
cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
};
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

    }



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 90%; float:left"></div>

  <div style="width: 10%; float:right">
    <select id="cmbMoreFunction" onchange="setPlaces()" >
        <option value="-1"><--Select--></option>
        <option value="bank">Banks</option>
        <option value="park">Parks</option>
        <option value="store">Stores</option>
     </select>

    </div>
    <select id="kilometers" onchange="setPlaces()" style="width: 10%; float:right">
     <option value="-1"><--Select--></option>   
     <option value="1000">1 KM</option>
     <option value="2000">2 KM</option>
     <option value="3000">3 KM</option>
</select>


   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: You explicitly remove the previous markers in your code, how do you expect that they will not disappear?

Comment: No,if i change for parks and shops all the parks/shops appers ! help me ! This happens only for banks

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select banks the request will always return 20 results(the maximum). There are e.g. still 2 banks within 1km(for me) when I select 2km.

There are also not all parks within 2km drawn when you select 3km(because there are more than 20 parks within 3 km, some of the parks within 2km are not included in the result for 3km).

That's how it is, a `nearbySearch` returns up to 20 results, not more.

You may use [`radarSearch()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests) instead, it returns up to 200 results.
But no matter which method you will use, there is no way to get all results(except there are less results than defined by the limits).

Comment: oh i will try radar search. thanks ! And  why results displaying outside the circle i have set both the circle radius and places radius as 1000 m .

Comment: There is a note in the documentation: *You may bias results to a specified circle by passing a location and a radius parameter. This will instruct the Places service to prefer showing results within that circle; **results outside of the defined area may still be displayed**.*

Comment: But i have gone through some websites that returns results exactly within the circle ! How could they do it ?

Comment: Maybe they perform an additionally filtering of the results, e.g. by using [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#spherical) . Also note: other sites may have other licenses, perhaps they get different results with a business-license

Comment: Do you know why listings by Indiacom yellow pages keeps on coming in right bottom .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, on http://www.indiacom.com/yellow-pages/ I see no map and listings in the middle of the page.

Comment: If you select banks for 1km ,2km ,3km . In the right bottom listings by indiacom yellowpages displays . Try removing marker.seticon segment in my code